# JasperReport scales images when exporting to PDF, thus losing quality

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report designed with iReport 1.3.0. This report includes several images, which are loaded dynamically. Then I use `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile` to create the PDF. Everything in the PDF looks fine except for the images, which appear scaled.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I've just downloaded and installed the newest version (4.0.0). I've tried a preview of the report, and the images still appear scaled. There must be some config parameter I'm missing, but I can't figure out which one. Please help!

Answer (score 9):

### About Images

If you save the report as HTML, you will notice that the logo appears correctly.

Image files such as PNG are raster images: stored as individual pixels.

Whereas PDF files are primarily vectorized: the elements inside are stored as descriptions of how to draw them. This allows PDFs to scale and be legible at any size.

Using a raster image in a vector format will likely result in a pixelated effect.

### Possible Solutions

You have a few options to make the images match the quality of the text, in order of ease:

- Create a version of the logo at 1200 dpi, scaled 400% larger.
- Create an SVG version of the logo.
- Convert the image to a vector format.
- Scale image 300% and change resolution to 288 dpi.

#### 1200 DPI Version

The image will look sharp until around 400% zoom.

#### SVG Version

The image will look sharp at every resolution. Replace the normal `<image...>` XML with the following code (be sure to adjust the width and height accordingly):

```
<image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="179" height="66"/>
 <imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.io.File("/path/to/logo.svg"))]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

#### Convert GIF to SVG

To convert a GIF to SVG, first try a quick web-based tool, such as: http://vectormagic.com

Once converted to SVG, you will have to use the code listed above to display the logo.

#### Resolution and Scale

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087
- http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/columns/ajs_resolution.html

Comment: There is no need to set the `class` property in more recent versions of JasperReports (in case you are wondering on how to set this on `JRDesignExpression`).

Comment: Resolution is what fixed me. I made the image huge and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 4.0.1 raster image resolution should be preserved and you can also improve the resolution of charts when using other export options (xls, rtf, html etc). The default is only a very low 72 dpi.

In iReport Options > JasperReport Properties edit

*net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi*            ***300***

http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=3411

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions you need to configure the `net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi` property globally by defining a `jasperreports.properties` file inside `WEB-INF/classes/` folder with this line in it:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi=300
```

A server restart is also needed.