# How/Can I use base64 as image source in a Jasper Report template?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, base64

So in my jrxml file I have the following:

```
<parameter name="smileyfaceimage" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Then I reference it in:

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement x="167" y="62" width="363" height="171" backcolor="#333333"/>
    <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{smileyfaceimage}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Is this not correct?

I've tried the base64 both with and without:

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

Here's the image im working with

[image: just a random screenshot]

Then I used https://www.base64-image.de/ or any random site to get the base64 string. I tested the string it produces and it's valid.

Now in my code;

- set the value of a variable to the based64 string
- on the template

  - set the parameter: `<parameter name="smileyfaceimage" class="java.lang.String"/>`
- then add the image data to the page:

  - ```
    <image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
        <reportElement x="167" y="62" width="363" height="171" backcolor="#333333"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($P{smileyfaceimage}.getBytes()))]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
    ```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Passing parameter as `String` makes jasper report believe its a absolute file path, so you need another class. The most obvious would be `java.awt.Image` or `java.io.InputStream`.

I choose `java.io.InputStream` since this will require less code, so the first thing we need to do now is to `decode` the `base64` image `String`.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) Base64 class that will do the job, I choose the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` since apache `commons-codec.jar` is already distributed with jasper report ([dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0)). The decode will give us a byte array `byte[]`, so now we need only to add a `ByteArrayInputStream`

The java code would be:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(smileyfaceimage.getBytes()));
```

Time to pass it into the jasper report `imageExpression`

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
<reportElement x="167" y="62" width="363" height="171" backcolor="#333333"/>
    <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($P{smileyfaceimage}.getBytes()))]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Hope for the best and press the **preview**:

[image: Result]

**Important notice**: The `smileyfaceimage` needs to be **without**:`data:image/png;base64,`

**EDIT**: The problem of the OP (comments) was that with old jasper report lib (3.0) you need to specify the class in the `imageExpression` @see `class="java.io.InputStream"` the post has been update consequently since this works also in 6.0.

Comment: nope(wish i had), im fixing some old old codebase so i dont even know how to get a stacktrace for it lol...

Comment: whelp, guess it must be my shitty codebase lol. i'll work with what u show me and hopefully get it working! thanks!

Comment: It starts with "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS" and ends with "ywAAAAASUVORK5CYII="

Comment: yep. that is exactly. im sure there's something in the code thats doing something stupid to cause this to not work. ive look around other solutions online and they look about the same as yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94455/discussion-between-yao-chen-and-petter-friberg).

Answer (score 6):

You need to decode the image somehow, e.g. use an imageExpression:

```
<image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Bottom" isUsingCache="false">
  <reportElement uuid="53a340b3-7d64-4104-9e9f-0f603059579a" key="Logo_Footer" x="55" y="760" width="370" height="42"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[new java.io.StringBufferInputStream(new org.w3c.tools.codec.Base64Decoder(" Base 64 String Data ").processString())]]>
  </imageExpression>
</image>
```

I'm using this to embed images, but it should work with a variable, field or parameter too.

Comment: this doesnt work for me, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8+ without external libraries:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode($P{barcodeHeader})))]]></imageExpression>
```

If that doesn't work, this should definitely:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode($P{barcodeHeader})))]]></imageExpression>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my oracle DB, I have clob datatype for the base64 image, but Jaspersoft studio supports only string format, so I added image expressions as below,
Image Expressions:

```
new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(new String($F{IMAGE_FRONT}).getBytes("UTF-8")))
```

Source:

```
  <image>
    <reportElement x="60" y="60" width="510" height="230" uuid="a06352ef-7ebf-4691-91a1-c8bc1371f90b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression>
    <![CDATA[new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(new String($F{CLOB_DATA_FIELD}).getBytes("UTF-8")))]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
```

Base64 is not defined issue is cleared after added jar file into MY REPORTS -> PROPERTIES -> JAVA BUILD PATH -> ADD EXTERNAL JAR ->jasperreports-6.1.0.jar
The jar file downloaded from
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions above and didn't work for me
I am currently using Jasper Reports Version 6.19.1 and found this Base64Util class at net.sf.jasperreports.util. You can look at it and check the method
that would help solve your problem

```
<image evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="400" y="50" width="154" height="84" uuid="fa0e76f4-ffe9-4090-8a5c-68683b97ac38"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.util.Base64Util.decode($P{photo})]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
```

$P{photo} it is my variable that contains the base64 string

The decode method returns a byte[] array to your ImageExpression

```java
public static byte[] decode(String data) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        decode(input, out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jasper 6.20.6.
I tried all the similar solution I found (on Stackoverflow, and on Jasper forum).
None worked.
The only way I found to make it work, is to completely remove the string parameter, and then put the base64 encoded image directly in the decodeBase64() call.

Here is the complete report code.
There are 2 picture, the first one use the string parameter, and it doesnt work, it get rendered as a blank box.
The second image use the base64 encoded image directly in the decodeBase64() call, and it seem to work.

Report jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.6.final utlizzo versione della libreria JasperReports6.20.6-5c96b6aa8a39ac1dc6b6bea4b81168e16dd39231  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test001" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1a700ddc-bfd8-437f-9138-b41487cbe1ea">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <variable name="myImg1" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["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"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="240" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="1c61fd46-226e-491b-9891-6050014f68f6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[test texte, test text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="70" y="10" width="190" height="210" uuid="21e88b95-1d09-4108-8cbf-dcf8b4b2ed9e"/>
                <box padding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($V{myImg1}.getBytes()))]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="310" y="10" width="190" height="210" uuid="28050615-9a40-48c3-b64b-1e6271ee9a95"/>
                <box padding="1">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64("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".getBytes()))]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="150" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="d00ab4fa-eb41-47c8-9bb0-0c7884b5c36a"/>
                <text><![CDATA[test text 2, test text 2, ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This report get rendered like this:

[image]

Any idea about why the imagebox that use the string parameter get rendered as a white box?