# How to export HTML text with embedded images (base64, data uri) using the htmlcomponent?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, base64

We have HTML from database, and we would like to create a Word report with this HTML. This HTML comes from users, and may contain only formatted text (bold, italic...), or text + embedded image encoded in base64 way.

Example:

```
<b>My photo :</b>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K... " />
```

We know that with `textField`, `markup="html"`, it does not work with `img` html tags. With Jasper Studio 6.3.1, we tried with `<hc:html/>`, it works with image on the hard drive, but it won't work with embedded image, saying there are syntax errors on the base64 encryption.

jrxml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StylesReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="53f914b8-f951-4433-971d-6b1819430c56">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.embed.image" value="true"/>
    <import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binar.*"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="515" height="30" uuid="c2015c9b-9130-4f39-a09e-c341c91d3794"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["HTML  Element  Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="230" height="110" backcolor="#ADD8E6" uuid="332dd551-e8cd-4cb0-a11f-7325f481017b"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<p style='background-color:yellow;font-family:verdana;font-size:50px;'>Hi, I am through HTML CODE using HTML Component</p><br><br><img src='data:image/gif;base64,/9j/dkjdkdkdkddk(INSERTIMAGEHEREITSTOOLONG!!!)' alt='Japser Architecture' height='1000' width='1800'>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Is it possible to do this with Jasper ? We wouldn't like to parse the HTML from database to do tons of things with, we really would like the HTML written as-is on the report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a nice challenge, the problem is that it's not supported but it does not mean that it can not be done.

The html component uses the [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) to render the html as an image and there is **no default protocol handler for "data:"**

However this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388757/5292302) by [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) shows how you can add one.

## Example

**jrxml** (htmlComponentBase64.jrxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StylesReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="53f914b8-f951-4433-971d-6b1819430c56">
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <textField hyperlinkType="Reference" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="515" height="30" uuid="c2015c9b-9130-4f39-a09e-c341c91d3794"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["HTML  Element  Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="230" height="110" backcolor="#ADD8E6" uuid="332dd551-e8cd-4cb0-a11f-7325f481017b"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<p style='background-color:yellow;font-family:verdana;font-size:50px;'>Hi, I am through HTML CODE using HTML Component</p><br><br><img src='data:image/gif;base64,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' alt='Japser Architecture' height='1000' width='1800'>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**java**

add Joop Eggen's protocol handler (remember to attribute him and maybe a nice upvote also) and execute this java code, in this case to export to pdf

```
public class TestReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {

        Handler.install(); //Install Joop's protocol handler
        
         //Compile report and fill, no datasource needed
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("htmlComponentBase64.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>());

        //Export to pdf
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/htmlcomponentbase64.pdf"));
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();

    }
}
```

**Enjoy the result**

[image: output]

*not the nicest report, but the image is displayed*

> I have added a [feature request](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/8971) in jasper-reports community, to include a data protocol handler in future release

Comment: We are testing, PDF is created, but image is not displayed :'( We used Joop's protocol handler and your code. What's version is it ?

Comment: We don't go through the `getInputStream()` from the Handler, and the handler seems to be not 'installed', because already present in the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system property.

Comment: Progress : Handler is installed, but we never go through it :(

Comment: What error do you have, I tested with v.6.1.1, remember to put htmlcomponent.jar in classpath and the handler needs to be in a package named data (I had all 3 files, mine + Joop's 2 in a package test.data

Comment: We use 6.3.1. We manage to make it works if all 3 files are in the same package, called data. Otherwise, it doesn't work. Problem is the report is generated in a service layer, so it's bit tricky to put everything in a package called data...

Comment: It works well for PDF. But when exporting in Word, but it seems the component is doing a SNAPSHOT of the HTML and copy the image in the word. So text is not modifiable... Is there a solution for that ?

Comment: @Guillaume no that component renders as an image, no solution using that, you need to create textElement etc.. hence do some dynamic implementation of your html, it will not be easy... see also 1 of my first comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737358/jasper-reports-show-images-from-html-source/33738593#comment69252694_33738593