# Jasper report spring boot app does not load base64 image

Tags: java, jasper-reports

my spring boot application uses jasper report to view the report below, but it does not load me a base64 image in the report, how can I solve? the parameters is LogoBase64

**Spring Boot Java App:**

```
Preventivo ptemp = p;
        try {
            List<TableReportPreventivo> tablevaluesList = new ArrayList<>();
            //Recupero valori setup reporty
            //boolean ris = Support.decodeBase64JPG(repoAzienda.getInfo().getLogo()) == false ? false : true;
            ptemp = repoPreventivo.getInfo(p.getIdPreventivo());
            p = ptemp;
            Cliente c = repoCliente.getOne(ptemp.getIdCliente());
            String base64image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + repoAzienda.getInfo().getLogo();
            //Carico le informazioni del preventivo del Preventivo
            Date dt = ptemp.getDataInserimento();
            Date dat = java.sql.Date.valueOf(String.valueOf(dt));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dat);
            TableReportPreventivo tablevalues = new TableReportPreventivo(dt.toString(), ptemp.getIdPreventivo() + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), ptemp.getRiferimentoInterno(), ptemp.getVostroRiferimento(), c.getTitolo(), c.getRagioneSociale(), c.getIndirizzo(), c.getCap() + " " + c.getCitta() + " " + c.getProvincia(), ptemp.getOggetto(), ptemp.getTestata(), "");
            ClassPathResource reportResource = new ClassPathResource("templates/reportpreventivo.jasper");
            Map<String, Object> reportParameters = new HashMap<>();
            tablevaluesList.add(tablevalues);
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tablevaluesList);
            reportParameters.put("Data", ptemp.getDataInserimento().toString());
            reportParameters.put("NRPreventivo", ptemp.getIdPreventivo() + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            reportParameters.put("NSRif", ptemp.getRiferimentoInterno());
            reportParameters.put("VSRif", ptemp.getVostroRiferimento());
            reportParameters.put("Titolo", c.getTitolo());
            reportParameters.put("RagioneSociale", c.getRagioneSociale());
            reportParameters.put("Indirizzo", c.getIndirizzo());
            reportParameters.put("Citta", c.getCitta());
            reportParameters.put("Testata", p.getTestata());
            reportParameters.put("Oggetto", p.getOggetto());
            reportParameters.put("LogoBase64", base64image);
            ReportService.exportReportToPDF(reportResource.getInputStream(), reportParameters, "report");
            if (rp.name().equals("STAMPAPREVENTIVOCOMPLETO")) {
                System.out.println("Stampa preventivo completo");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO è Stampa preventivo completo");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Errore: " + ex);

        }
        return ptemp;
```

**Jasper jrxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportpreventivo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3c08ffac-5031-449c-a58f-007dffeebf2f">
    <import value="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"/>
    <subDataset name="DataSetHeader" uuid="db6131ae-8b7b-429e-aaca-42479bc8befd">
        <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Data del preventivo]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <variable name="Logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Data" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NRPreventivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="VSRif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Titolo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="RagioneSociale" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Indirizzo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Citta" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Oggetto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Testata" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LogoBase64" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="79" uuid="7fe6f2e0-3ba7-4424-9383-8d78bfe1cc21"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{LogoBase64}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="430" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="15" width="40" height="30" uuid="801816f2-1988-4b9e-9291-88d5a200d238"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Data:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="15" width="100" height="30" uuid="29f6924b-5bd2-42f1-bd98-0090aed0d3eb"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Data}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="50" width="90" height="30" uuid="c59e786f-e907-4bcd-93f3-a14d0b777d5c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nr Preventivo:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="50" width="100" height="30" uuid="b0632e23-c54a-4edc-a264-23055af446a5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NRPreventivo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="80" width="90" height="30" uuid="c5dbd3b3-7263-43d5-a804-1a797635fe8a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nf.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="80" width="100" height="30" uuid="1a11a6cc-5d1b-4994-bf10-3cc1de504d07"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{NSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="110" width="90" height="30" uuid="dc708ab1-3286-479d-ad0b-aaea351652b4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vs.Rif:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="aac1e4b6-da6a-4e46-aa0f-c026896a3b86"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{VSRif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="15" width="100" height="25" uuid="7231c72c-d715-4bbe-8906-a27173f77220"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Titolo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="50" width="170" height="30" uuid="caf5fd23-70c3-46d3-9de0-c5765c1ec5fc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{RagioneSociale}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="80" width="170" height="30" uuid="ec9b01f4-bcb2-495f-9a54-efc48bb452c8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Indirizzo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="110" width="170" height="30" uuid="9174f886-5c23-4f99-9c97-86fb50f6eeb3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Citta}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="50" y="180" width="500" height="30" uuid="089a3b80-f7df-461b-be75-bcad575bf4e9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Oggetto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="50" y="220" width="500" height="210" uuid="a5a724e9-c81f-470a-8a83-9dd6bfbd823d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Testata}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="69" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="470" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="980219d2-fe09-46a6-ad45-44b5a5d955dd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Probably you need to decode the image : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571520/how-can-i-use-base64-as-image-source-in-a-jasper-report-template

Comment: @PeterMmm your solutonions not works