# Display image exported as byte array in JasperReports

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I am trying to export image(byte array) and display in PDF using iReport. Groovy code:

```
        InvoiceVO invoiceVO = new InvoiceVO()
        invoiceVO.kms = 5
         ..............
        invoiceVO.image = currentUser.profile.image // byte array
```

In iReport I am using:

```
    <image>
        <reportElement x="2" y="7" width="143" height="32" uuid="df5cd1ab-e7a2-41a1-920d-6045db41cfc9"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage($F{image})]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
```

but its not working. Field image is of type "java.lang.object" also tried "java.lang.byte". Image expression place-holder displays blank.

Comment: `but its not working` - What does it mean (got some error, ...)?  What is a type of `$F{image}`?

Comment: java.lang.object also tried java.lang.byte

Comment: I updated the question. Its displaying blank in image place-holder.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087

Answer (score 2):

The method *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage(byte[])* is absent (obsolete) in *JasperReports API 6.x*.

You should pass *java.awt.Image* object to the report.

Converting `byte[]` to `java.awt.Image` can be done in a chain.

*Java* code:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/smile.png")) {
    params.put("smileImage", ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(JRLoader.loadBytes(inputStream))));
} catch (JRException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load image", e);
}
```

The *jrxml* file:

```
<parameter name="logo" class="java.awt.Image"/>
<summary>
    <band height="150">
        <image >
            <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{smileImage}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```