# adding image using java bean as a data source in jasper reports

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm using a Java bean as a datasource for my report and it's doing fine with normal types, but I have no idea how to use it for an image, searching on the web only gave me ways on how to do this using other data sources than a java bean, I'm using `jasper soft` studio to design the reports.

This is how I usualy write the code for this:

**Sample bean**:

```
public class SampleBean{

    String name;
    //image type?????!!

    public SampleBean( String name) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return entrepriseNom;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

**print report method**:

```
public void printReport() {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.jasper");
            JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(stream);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, getData());                
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my answer from [Display a byte array as an image in a JasperReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547588/display-a-byte-array-as-an-image-in-a-jasperreport).

Answer (score 0):

mmm with byte u can solve that

private byte[] photo;