# Set Dynamic Image Path Using Jasper Report and Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper report 6. I'have been creating a report with an image. this image is located at my local drive. I try to call this report from my app project.The image doesn't appear when i'm running in app. but it appear in Jasper. 
How can I set the image path to appear at my applications root and not from my local drive?

I try to using parameter for the image like this, but it's still error :

```
if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("PrintAlasanPenolakan")) {
    File reportFile = new File(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/reportListAlasanPenolakan.jasper"));
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        dataReportAlasanPenolakan = dbReportAlasanPenolakan.getAllAlasanPenolakanReport();
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("user", (String) session.getAttribute("user_id"));
        model.put ("Image", (String) this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/logo.png"));
        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), model, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataReportAlasanPenolakan));
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Error Print PDF:" + e.getMessage());
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
    } finally {
        dbConn.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: which error appears?

Comment: error is appear like net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at :

Comment: Also of possible interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087