# How to show byte array of Image data in JRXML Jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using **JasperSoft-6** tool.

I am creating `Field` of type `java.util.String`, and trying to associate to my Image element using below code
`new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($F{std}.getBytes()))`

Finally from java I am trying to set this way

```
byte[] data = imagesRepo.findByUserId(Long.valueOf(22)).getPicByte();
            System.out.println("Image length : "+data.length);
//            dataSource.put("imageData", data);
//            dataSource.put("imageData", CommonFileUtils.decompressBytes(data));
            
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new 
            ByteArrayInputStream(data);//CommonFileUtils.decompressBytes(data)
            dataSource.put("imageData", imageStream);
```

Still I am not able to render the image, surprisingly no errors while generating report. report is generated but images are blank.

I tried to follow this blog from stackoverflow but still no luck
[How to display a svg byte array as an image in a JasperReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547588/how-to-display-a-svg-byte-array-as-an-image-in-a-jasperreport)